# How can I make my Oracle APEX application on my laptop accessible from public internet?

Tags: networking, windows-xp, port-forwarding

I have a virtual machine with windows XP.

Oracle APEX is configured and working.

I opened my router settings and added the following in the forward rules > port mapping configuration:

- **internal host**: XP MACHINE IP ADDRESS
- **protocol**: TCP
- **External & Internal port numbers**: 8080 - 8080

Saved the settings & restarted the XP virtual machine.

Now, I'm trying to access the Oracle APEX from an external network while my XP machine is on by:

- http://IPADDRESS:8080/apex

However it is not working.

I added 8080 port in the firewall exceptions but still failing.

Any ideas?

Comment: You do understand most non-commercial ISPs prevent you from hosting a website/application right?  It being set to port 8080 won't change the traffic that is being transmitted.

Comment: How could I confirm if my ISP is blocking this or not? I'm not trying to host something, I'm doing all this for development purposes only.

Comment: If the VM where the web application is installed on, is accessible from outside of your network, then thats considered hosting said application..

Comment: I have a plex media server and its using port 32400 which I forwarded through the router as well and it is working fine, could the ISP block certain ports? or the plex media server managed to forward port 32400?

Comment: There is a simple enough solution to your problem, you can connect all the machines, to the same VPN.  This will remove your ISP from the equation.  You can verify if the traffic is being blocked by using a port other than 8080, which is so commonly used as an alternative to port 80, it would not be shocked its simply blocked.  There are also services, which indicate if they can see traffic on a port, it very well could be an Apex configuration problem.  Typically you have to go out of the way, to allow traffi, from outside of a network the service is running on.

Comment: I figured out that I can't access the VM from other computers on the same network "192.168.100.10:8080/apex" and even when pinging from other computers to this VM the destination host is unreachable. Anything I need to check from here?

Comment: running arp -a from the VM gets only the router. running arp -a from any other machine it gets everything except the VM. So the VM seems to be isolated.

Comment: If your VM is running inside VMWare or VirtualBox, then there usually different possibilities in which you can run the VM: 1) either bridged-mode in which you can see the VM from inside your home network (and from the internet if your router _and_ ISP allow it), OR, 2) the default is that VirtualBox/VMWare places the VM behind its own NAT, and then you also need to configure port-forwarding in VirtualBox/VMWare. Basically you are forwarding ports from your local PC to the virtual machine which is running behind a NAT inside your PC. But in my case I already did this and APEX still doesnt work.

Comment: @SorinPostelnicu I posted this a year ago and I don't remember any details. I just remember that I solved it by connecting my laptop to a cable instead of wireless. I was able to connect from outside my home network perfectly and APEX was working but the connection was continually breaking. Let me know what exactly isn't working with you.